# Apache virtual host permissions not working

Tags: apache, virtualhost, file-permissions

I need some help here my virtual hosts permissions appear not to be working.
For example site1.com and site2.com can access each others files and even create files!. I have tried to prevent this by having this in the apache2.conf file.

```
<Directory />
  Options FollowSymLinks
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
</Directory>
```

And then in the virtual host file for site1 I have this

```
<Directory /var/www/site1.com/public_html>
     Options indexes, FollowSymLinks
     Order Allow,Deny
     Allow from all
</Directory>
```

And for the virtual host ifle in site2 I have this

```
<Directory /var/www/site2.com/public_html>
         Options indexes, FollowSymLinks
         Order Allow,Deny
         Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

Can anyone help me with this please as its a big security issue?

What have I done wrong?

Thanks,
 Dan

Answer (score 0):

An  Apache configuration doesn't have anything to do with who/what can create files in the filesystem, it only determines what this particular program (httpd) is willing to serve.